# Everpad installation error, pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: PySide

Tags: software-installation, evernote, pyside

I have installed EVERPAD a client for Evernote by following way in my Ubuntu 12.04lts 32bit but I am getting the following error, can anybody fix this.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nvbn-rm/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install everpad
```

When I am typing $everpad in terminal I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/everpad", line 5, in <module>
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2735, in <module>
working_set.require(__requires__)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 690, in require
needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 588, in resolve
raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: PySide
```

Comment: Try this: `sudo apt-get install python-pyside`, let me know.

Comment: No it did not worked .. same error

Comment: I am having the same issue, although my traceback is reporting the error on a different line count to what is described above.

I've tried removing Everpad and installed all the mentioned python packages etc but still not had any luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem today.  Can't start Everpad.  Killed all Everpad related processes, no difference.
Did the "sudo apt-get install python-pyside", still no luck.
Get the following if I try to run "everpad --verbose" from command-line:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/everpad", line 5, in 
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2805, in 
    working_set.require(**requires**)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 696, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 594, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: PySide

Answer (score 0):

I have been using everpad for nearly a year. Last week I updated Ubuntu 12.04 by using the hwe packages to update the kernel to 3.5.0. Everpad was still working okay. Then an update to everpad came through and it will now not start.
I get the same error as above.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/everpad", line 5, in 
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2707, in 
    working_set.require(**requires**)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 686, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 584, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: PySide

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, I tried testing Everpad in a live boot and still had the same issue. The latest repositories just do not like the PySide module. A little research suggests its to do with latest 'sqlalchemy' version I believe (could be wrong there so don't quote me on that).

I have managed to move it passed the PySide error. I now get it stuck here:

```
$ everpad
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/everpad", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('everpad==2.6.1dev', 'gui_scripts', 'everpad')()
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 353, in load_entry_point    
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2321, in load_entry_point
    return ep_map
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2048, in load
    if req.specs: raise ValueError
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/everpad/pad/indicator.py", line 8, in <module>
    from everpad.pad.editor import Editor
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/everpad/pad/editor/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from everpad.interface.editor import Ui_Editor
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/everpad/interface/editor.py", line 125, in <module>
    from PySide import QtWebKit
ImportError: cannot import name QtWebKit
```

I have found the below link which managed to get me this. It took me a little longer for me to get this far because I had a few other problems along the way, but it may work for you:

https://github.com/nvbn/everpad/issues/401

Looks like the issue is with the PySide install not having the .egg-info. Apparently something to do with the way apt-get installs python-pyside. However it doesn't seem to install the PySide.QTWebKit module correctly.

The link above pretty much just suggests installing PySide via `pip install pyside` but I seem to have problems directly with importing QTWebKit from the PySide module in the python interpreter. I'll update this post if I manage to get passed this QTWebKit issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install cmake and libqt4-dev to install pyside. Afterwards, it couldn't find the installation, so I added the egg-info according to the in the [this post on github](https://github.com/nvbn/everpad/issues/401). Everpad would start without errors but I wouldn't see the applet on the menu bar nor would it start. I had to restart my computer but it now works.

Comment: Interesting you managed to get get Everpad to launch after installing PySide. Did your PySide install into /usr/lib or /usr/local/lib? And how did you go about installing PySide? Did you use 'pip install pyside' or a manual build method?

Comment: It installed in /usr/local/lib/(python2.7/dist-packages/PySide/). I used pip install. I installed libpyside through pip too.

Comment: did your pip install pyside fail when trying to run pyside_postinstall.py? Did you run it manually? And finally do you have QtWebKit in your /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PySide directory?

Comment: The pyside installation did fail because I didn't have cmake of libqt4 installed. Afterwards I just ran pip install pyside and it installed. Are you trying to manually install it? It took a while to install pyside for me. I have QTWebKit installed in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PySide/include/PySide/QtWebKit

Comment: Weird. I managed to get it working on another fresh install. There must have been another change to the repository because on the fresh install I added the ppa and then ran `apt-get install everpad` and it all worked. I need to investigate this one on my laptop though so will pair the two up and investigate further.